# Display a path in my maps android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried to develop a android app with maps. I'm a beginner in android app development, i doesn't know how to generate a path between my current position and to the destination. I can able to view by current location by the code shown below.

```
   package com.example.myapp;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Grandinmaps extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grandinmaps);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(12.971907, 80.220462), 18));

    }
}
```

And i doesn't know the code to generate the path to destination. 
Any HELP...!!! Please:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Drawing Route you can use this code:

Call for printing location route:

```
   GmapV2Direction route;
   Document document;

 LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(routeData.get(i).latitude, routeData.get(i).longitude);
                        new GetRouteTask() {
                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                                super.onPostExecute(s);
                            }
                        }.execute((LatLng) toPosition);



private class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String> {

        String response = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            document = route.getDocument(fromPosition, params[0], GmapV2Direction.MODE_WALKING);//fromPosition is another LatLng object.can be your current location.
            response = "Success";
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            // directionMap.clear();

            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                Log.v("Map", "got here");
                ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = route.getDirection(document);
                PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                        Color.RED);

                for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                }
                // Adding route on the map

                map.addPolyline(rectLine);
            }

        }
    }
```